# How to downgrade version of jar file without the project?

Tags: java, jar, downgrade

I have an old jar file with my library which use jdk 1.7.0_03. But on my new computer I did't have applicable version of jdk. My current version is 1.6. Is it possible to downgrade version of jar file (1.7 -> 1.6) without project source files so that my jar file could run on java 1.6?

Comment: This is not be possible due to it being compiled code. Your only solution would be to get 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to unpack a jar file with the "jar" CLI Tool and change the Version in the Manifest file.
Then you need to Repack the file again.
This worked for me once with an OSGi Bundle.

Comment: This is unlikely to work.  Or more precisely, it would only work if the classes were already compiled for a Java 1.6 target.

Answer (score 1):

You can't possibly downgrade a .jar file since it contains compiled code. If that code uses 1.7 features you are stuck. You can try running it on 1.6 though. If you have luck it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to downgrade version of jar file

No. you need to recompile the JAR

> without project source files

You need the source-file to recompile. you can decompile the class files, but it's not that easy

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [bytecode backporting tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_backporting_tools).  While such tools exist, there isn't one (AFAIK) that converts Java 7 bytecodes to Java 6 or earlier.

By the way, using the `jar` command to replace the manifest won't help.  The Java classfile format is versioned, and the version number changed between 1.6 and 1.7.  A Java 6 JVM cannot cope with a Java 1.7 (or later) classfile, irrespective of the JAR manifest.

Comment: @JaseC - That is none of your concern.